# Deploying Android app using Azure DevOps and editing APK for different environments

Tags: android, xamarin, azure-devops

this is a conceptual/design question.

We have a `Xamarin Forms` apps and I'm creating a build and release pipeline for the Android version in Azure DevOps.
We have 4 environments in total, internal, RC, staging and production.
For each of those I have created a `powershell` pre-build script that changes some configuration xml files, the app icons (different colours for different environments) and even the app name and package name (this way we can have all 4 installed on one device and be able to test using the different servers)

Now I have a build in DevOps which runs the pre-build script to modify all those things, builds the project, signs the `apk` and publishes it. In my release pipeline, I cannot use this logic because I need to be able to deploy the different apps to their own test groups in `App Center`.
So I decided to split the build, it would just build and then the release pipeline would have stages - alpha would run the script and modify the app and sign it and put it for testing in an Alpha group, the Beta stage to beta etc...

However, this means I have to modify the `.apk` after it was produced using powershell. For example, the `Android Manifest` file's content doesn't look like XML anymore and has strange `NUL`, `DLE` and other symbols in it. It'd make my life harder.

Do I build all 4 packages in my Build pipeline with prepared packages for all environments? This would increase the time a lot so it's undesirable but it'd save me from having to edit APKs later...

What are best practices in these kind of situations, what are you able to suggest I do, change the way I do everything or what?

Comment: Since sign the apk must finished in CI, why not try with build with different sign parallel? Then pass the value with variable to build apk with different sign.